# Is it possible to create a post using a metabox?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, wp-insert-post, save-post

I am trying to create a post (well, in the end, multiple posts) from a metabox using the 'save_post' hook. I executed the script once, creating 3900 or so new posts before I crawled into posts.php and discovered that wp_insert_post() calls the 'save_post' hook. Does anyone have a creative solution around this to create the post without doing a direct db insert (the less hacky the solution is the better).

## Code

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_metabox_init' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_metabox_save' );
function my_metabox_init()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'my-metabox',
        'My Metabox',
        'my_metabox_render'
        'post',
        'normal',
        'core'
    );
    //enquque scripts and styles
}
function my_metabox_render() {
    //generate datasets
}
function my_metabox_save() {
    //data authenticity check
    //process & sanitize data

    //create posts
    for( $i=0; $i<$count; $i++ ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_status' => 'pending',
            'post_title'  => $_POST['post_title'][$i],
            'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type',
        );
        foreach( $category_array[$i] as $category ) {
            $args['tax_input']['custom-taxonomy'][] = $category;
        }
        if( $_POST['id_of_previously_created_post'][$i] != '' ) {
            $args['ID'] = $_POST['id_of_previously_created_post'][$i];
            unset( $args['post_status'] );
        }
        $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you please explain better ? why do you want to create thousands of posts without saving them ? where do you want them to be ??

Comment: It created 3900 posts unintentionally, they were all duplicates of each other because in the function which I hooked to 'save_post', I called wp_insert_post() which has a do_action('save_post') call in it, so the program got stuck in an infinite loop of post creation until the script timeout hit. I'm looking to use a native wordpress function to create a post (with a custom post type) using the 'save_post' hook.

Does that make my situation any clearer?

Comment: your situation is clear . what is not clear to me is why you want to create a post without putting it inside the db ? do you want it to only SHOW on the editor every time ? wp_insert_post() is , like the name , inserting the post to the db (As it should). do you mean you want to programatically create a post from variables ? if so , creating 3900 posts is not the hook problem, but something in your function loop, or it´s location for execution. if you will post the code it would be more clear , at least to me .

Comment: The issue is, I'm relatively certain, that I am doing an add_action( 'save_post', 'my_plugin_save' ) and my_plugin_save() is calling wp_insert_post(), which in turn calls do_action( 'save_post' ), thus creating a loop. What I need to do to resolve this is either use a different hook, or use a different method of inserting into the $prefix.posts table...or potentially, I suppose, prevent save_post from making multiple passes. What code would you like to see? (this section is 200-300 lines, I can probably cut it to 50 or so)

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? What situation is creating the need to insert posts on save? If you are creating unique posts, you can first check if the post exists before running `wp_insert_post()` Should prevent it from getting stuck in a loop. I've done something similar when creating posts based on the main/first/original post's meta.

Comment: why not use only wp_insert_post($new_post); in add_action ? you can also check wp_insert_post_data (filter ) or update_post

Comment: `add_action( 'save_post', 'my_metabox_save' );
function my_metabox_save() {
 //data authenticity check
 //process & sanitize data

 //create posts
 for( $i=0; $i<$count; $i++ ) {
  $args = array(
   'post_status' => 'pending',
   'post_title'  => $_POST['post_title'][$i],
   'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type',
  );
  foreach( $category_array[$i] as $category ) {
   $args['tax_input']['custom-taxonomy'][] = $category;
  }
  if( $_POST['ID'][$i] != '' ) {
   $args['ID'] = $_POST['ID'][$i];
   unset( $args['post_status'] );
  }
  $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
 }
}`

Comment: I don't know why my formatting on that went to hell...I'll gladly repost if someone can tell me how to correct it. The only part of that that might be a bit confusing is the fact that it's in a loop, I'm doing this because I'm dealing with sets of data, so I (potentially) have multiple fields with name='post_title[]', thus making them arrays. I've successfully used this method before to handle sets of data, both with wordpress and just in general PHP dev.

The idea here is to provide an alternate method of data entry for the client and to associate related custom-post-type posts with posts.

Comment: I put the code in pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/0yWQuktx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, what I ended up doing was as follows:

```php
function my_metabox_save() {
    //do this just once
if( MY_DOING_SAVE != 'my_doing_save' ) {
    define( MY_DOING_SAVE , 'my_doing_save' );

    //data authenticity check
    //process & sanitize data

    //create posts
    for( $i=0; $i<$count; $i++ ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_status' => 'pending',
            'post_title'  => $_POST['post_title'][$i],
            'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type',
        );
        foreach( $category_array[$i] as $category ) {
            $args['tax_input']['custom-taxonomy'][] = $category;
        }
        if( $_POST['id_of_previously_created_post'][$i] != '' ) {
            $args['ID'] = $_POST['id_of_previously_created_post'][$i];
            unset( $args['post_status'] );
        }
        $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
        }
    }
}
```

The reason @toscho's method did not work was because of the scope of the variable, he was on the right track for sure though.

Comment: You probably missed the _static_ keyword in your test. You don’t need something in a global scope, just in your function.

Comment: No, I did use the static keyword...it's just not in a class, so that didn't work :P I wasn't really thinking when I tried it, I just sorta did it blindly, and I'm not as strong as I would like to be at OOPHP, so it didn't raise a flag for me. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The _static_ keyword in my example is not OOP, it just makes sure the value is available in all calls to this function. [See the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static). Make sure your constant never interferes with other code. The global scope of a constant is one of the major drawbacks for constants, that’s why I avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: Ah, sweet...learn something new every day! In that case though, the issue with your solution was that static was being set every time the function was called, rather than being set only the first time...I'm actually going to try to implement this using static, I'll update the answer if it works.

Comment: Nope, tried it and it did not work...I'm not entirely sure why (I just did a one for one replace with the static variable). If you have any ideas as to why, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

The answer is so simple, I couldn’t see it at first. :)

Just remove the action during the first function call. This way, your work **within the API**, and your function is really called just once. No need for static or even global variables or constants.

```
function my_metabox_save() {
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'my_metabox_save' );
    // go on with your function ...
```

I’ll leave the old answer to illustrate how awkward a solution may get if you think too abstract …

### Old answer

Add a check to `my_metabox_save()` to prevent a second call.

Sample code (not tested):

```php
function my_metabox_save() {
    static $done = FALSE;
    if ( $done )
    { // No, not again!
        return;
    }
    //data authenticity check
    //process & sanitize data

    //create posts
    for( $i=0; $i<$count; $i++ ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_status' => 'pending',
            'post_title'  => $_POST['post_title'][$i],
            'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type',
        );
        foreach( $category_array[$i] as $category ) {
            $args['tax_input']['custom-taxonomy'][] = $category;
        }
        if( $_POST['id_of_previously_created_post'][$i] != '' ) {
            $args['ID'] = $_POST['id_of_previously_created_post'][$i];
            unset( $args['post_status'] );
        }
        $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
    }
    $done = TRUE; // Remember that we’re done.
}
```

Comment: I just tried this (and I had tried a slightly different implementation before, forgot to mention, apologies) and it did not work. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Try _exactly_ this approach. It works.

Comment: I did try this, it had the same effect as if it were not there (whole BUNCH of posts). The script cannot even run to completion, it hits the loop on `do_action( 'save_post' )` within `/wp-includes/post.php` and then it starts `my_metabox_save()` again. It will never even make it out of the `//create posts` `for()` loop, it just nests them. I'm currently trying a post-title comparison method, I'll update in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a wp_nonce check before saving the post 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field
Once is saved the first time , the wp_nonce will be disgregated and no more calls to wp_insert_post will be done

Comment: I'm already doing an nonce at the `//data authenticity check`, thanks for answering though